# how to send emails in jsp using securesocketlayer?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have been using java mail to send mail from jsp to send emails.

But google is blocking my request and I am getting a message from gmail to my inbox as **Signin attempt blocked**.

In order to send mails from my account I have to update my security setting access permission to less secureapps but I don't want to do it.

So how to send mails using ssl in java mail?

The sample code I am using is:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

The "less secure apps" setting has nothing to do with SSL.  It's required to allow you to login using just a username and password, instead of using the (more complicated, but presumably more secure) [OAuth2](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2) authentication technique.